# Delete Features from a feature class that participates in a topology

Tags: arcgis-desktop, topology, arccatalog, feature-class, feature-dataset

I have an enterprise geodatabase and I would like to delete features using the tool from a feature class that resides in one of the feature datasets and participates in a topology.  I tried using the tool, but it just churns and churns, ArcCatalog locks up and stops responding.  Is this possible to delete all the features, not the feature class if it participates in a topology?  It is part of a replication.  We get data from somewhere else and we just load in the new data to keep our schema.  The schema is the same for the new data.  I tried doing it from a version and also in ArcMap with locks and not responding.

Answer (score 2):

The issue here is that for features that participate in a Geodatabase Topology or Geometric Network all changes *must* be enclosed in an edit operation... direct quote:

> Situations requiring edit sessions The following includes some dataset
>   types that can only be edited within an edit session: Feature classes
>   participating in a topology Feature classes participating in a
>   geometric network Versioned datasets in ArcSDE geodatabases Some
>   object and feature classes with class extensions

If you're doing this in python you will need to use StartEditing and StopEditing (see [arcpy.da.Editor](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018w00000005000000) for more) or use [DeleteFeatures](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001700000036000000) in ArcMap whilst editing.